# Laravel model events parameter

Tags: laravel, events, model

I want create a Project for user when register on the site. I tried this code but I can't pass Project class.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function ($user) {
        $project = new Project();
        $project->title = trans('messages.first_project');
        $project->owner_id = $user->id;
        $project->save();
        $project->users()->attach([$user->id]);
    });
}
```

Error: Class 'Project' not found

Comment: Why don't you use seeding?

Comment: What's the error you got

Comment: Error: Class 'Project' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'Use App\Project' at the top of your file.